# On navigation of page after code is stopped, web page shouldn't be displayed

Tags: angular

If Angular application or the code is stopped, then in browser we are able to see web page. But on redirection or navigation of page still I am able to see web pages but with broken functionalities as code is not running. How to handle this or display server has stopped?

Answer (score 1):

Basically Angular 2+ is not designed to work off of the file system without a web server. If you really need to serve an angular 2+ app from the file system I would consider electron as a better solution. Otherwise, you can use `lite-server` a very lightweight development web server.

In development we normal use :

```
ng serve
```

If you are looking to deploy your application for production  first build the project using

```
ng build --prod
```

And now you get bundled project in `dist` folder inside a folder with project name. You can just copy these files to some web server or host it like any normal html file on any web server.

Comment: But when we do ng serve, it is being hosted on a web server which is using "express" implicitly. I am running application through ng serve.

Comment: @RaghavGupta yes you are, but when you stop the `ng serve` command basically you are stopping the server . Angular being  client side application will still have its files in your browser  you may feel its working but its not. sine you were using live reload along some of the files may be missing in your browser as the server stopped serving  and the application breaks on navigation which is expected behaviour

Comment: Ok, so suppose I deploy this application on server like tomcat and then somebody is using this application. If tomcat server stops while a user is logged in then also he would be able to navigate. Then also angular files would be in browser. Isn't it?

Comment: in such case there wont be any issue unless you are lazy loading some modules or reload the page or app in web browser .  This problem  happens in development (ng serve) because you are using live reloading and all files are being watched by.

Comment: But when I do npm start which is a production build, it is not live reloading. It should as well handle this. What is the issue there?

Comment: @RaghavGupta that is the intended behaviour. live reloading is only for development    please read the official doc https://angular.io/guide/build#building-and-serving-angular-apps  and https://angular.io/cli/build